# How to format a book-style table with multicolumns and \cline?

Tags: tables, formatting, multicolumn, booktabs, cline

I read lots of similar question but I did not manage to fit to my case. I need to get a table with 2 multicolumns.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{
c
S[round-mode=places,round-precision=3] %col4
S[round-mode=places,round-precision=3,scientific-notation = true] %col4
S[round-mode=places,round-precision=2] %col4
S[round-mode=places,round-precision=2,scientific-notation = true] %col4
}
\toprule
\textbf{Lagrange\_point} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}x- coordinate \\ (au) \hspace{1cm}   (km)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}y- coordinate \\ (au) \hspace{1cm}  (km)\end{tabular}}} \\ \midrule
1 & -0.98998598231694 & -148099794.977462 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & -1.0100752000489 & -151105099.174192 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 1.00000126684309 & 149598060.217029 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & -0.499996959576574 & -74798480.5091294 & 0.866025403784439 & 129555556.37826 \\
5 & -0.499996959576574 & -74798480.5091294 & -0.866025403784439 & -129555556.37826 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Here is the results (I inserted red lines to give and idea of columns to group):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`booktabs` also provides `\cmidrule[](){}` to draw only part of a horizontal line. In the solution below, I changed the multiple `tabular`s to one `\multirow{}*{}`, which slightly simplifies code. Also, consider adding `table-format` as an option to the `S`-type column.

I'd personally move horizontal lines with gaps in the middle, so here are two versions of the table

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\sisetup{
    round-mode=places,
    uncertainty-mode = separate,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:my-table}
    \begin{tabular}{
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.75cm}
    S[table-format=-1.3, round-precision=3] %col4
    S[table-format=-1.3e1, round-precision=3, scientific-notation = true] %col4
    S[table-format=-1.2, round-precision=2] %col4
    S[table-format=-1.2e1, round-precision=2, scientific-notation = true] %col4
    }
    \toprule
    \textbf{Lagrange}
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{x- coordinate}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{y- coordinate}} \\
    \textbf{point}
    & \phantom{$-$}\textbf{(au)}
    & \textbf{(km)}
    & \phantom{$-$}\textbf{(au)}
    & \textbf{(km)} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    1 & -0.98998598231694 & -148099794.977462 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & -1.0100752000489 & -151105099.174192 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 1.00000126684309 & 149598060.217029 & 0 & 0 \\
    4 & -0.499996959576574 & -74798480.5091294 & 0.866025403784439 & 129555556.37826 \\
    5 & -0.499996959576574 & -74798480.5091294 & -0.866025403784439 & -129555556.37826 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:my-table11}
    \begin{tabular}{
    c
    S[table-format=-1.3, round-precision=3] %col4
    S[table-format=-1.3e1, round-precision=3, scientific-notation = true] %col4
    S[table-format=-1.2, round-precision=2] %col4
    S[table-format=-1.2e1, round-precision=2, scientific-notation = true] %col4
    }
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}*[-2pt]{\textbf{\parbox{1.75cm}{\centering Lagrange\\point}}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{x- coordinate}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{y- coordinate}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    & \phantom{$-$}\textbf{(au)}
    & \textbf{(km)}
    & \phantom{$-$}\textbf{(au)}
    & \textbf{(km)} \\
    \midrule
    1 & -0.98998598231694 & -148099794.977462 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & -1.0100752000489 & -151105099.174192 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 1.00000126684309 & 149598060.217029 & 0 & 0 \\
    4 & -0.499996959576574 & -74798480.5091294 & 0.866025403784439 & 129555556.37826 \\
    5 & -0.499996959576574 & -74798480.5091294 & -0.866025403784439 & -129555556.37826 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Celdor. Can you show how to split `Lagrange points` on two lines? I tried `\newline` and `\\` but they do not work!

Comment: @Giuseppe I updated the answer. In your case this is very simple. It is a matter of moving the second word to the next row. In my case, since I have added rules in the middle, so the two rows are slightly stretched. It's better to keep the text within the `\multirow`. I also enclosed the text in `\parbox`. This is one way to make `\newline` and \\ available in tables. Another option is to turn cells to a paragraph, e.g. by using `p{}` instead of `l` or `c` etc.